# how do I redirect to external URL using angularjs routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to have my site visitors go to a specific subdomain based on routeParams

for example if they go to "http://example.com/foo" they will be redirected to "http://foo.example.com"

Can I do that using the routeProvider with something like:

```
    $routeProvider
        .when('/:my_affiliate', {
            redirectTo: function(routeParams){
                return 'http://' + routeParams.my_affiliate + '.example.com';
            },
      })
        ;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with `routeProvider` how you state. If you want to redirect a user to a different subdomain use `window.location` with the desired URL. However, consider this will take you of your application. This may however be what you were expecting :D

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/:my_affiliate', {
        redirectTo: function(routeParams) {
            window.location = 'http://' + routeParams.my_affiliate + '.example.com';
        }
    });
```

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: That did work. Thanks. But is this the best way to do something like this?

Comment: It's not really a common use case to be handled by the client side. However, this approach is a safe bet. Normally any rerouting would be handled server side and taken out of the hands of the client.